# Extract Original Email Sender from Text Body Using Regex in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have extracted an inbox to csv and the body of each email is output in the following format:

```
"From: Name email@email.co.uk mailto:Name@email.co.uk text text text"
```

These are almost uniformly long chain emails but I need a way to get the original sender.

At the moment, I have been using a regex pattern to grab emails from each body of text, then grab the final email in that list:

```
list_emails = unlist(regmatches(text, gregexpr("([_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,4}))", 
                                          text, ignore.case = TRUE)))

# The last item in that list is the last one found within the body of the email and our likely original sender
list_emails[length(list_emails)]
```

This works if the original email has their address in their signature but grabs the final person copied in (cc'd) if they do not.

What I want is to edit this to only grab the emails preceded by the string pattern 'From: ' and then I can grab the final item in this new list. This will be the fastest way to get the original sender.

Is there a way to edit my original pattern to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a PCRE regex like

```
text <- "From: Name email@email.co.uk mailto:Name@email.co.uk text text text"
rx <- "From:.*\\K\\b[_a-z0-9-]+(?:\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\\.[a-z]{2,4}\\b"
unlist(regmatches(text, gregexpr(rx, text, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE)))
## => [1] "Name@email.co.uk"
```

See the [R demo online](https://rextester.com/RRC41821) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u7UDl0/1).

Note the use of the `perl=TRUE` argument. The main difference is the addition of `From:.*\K\b` at the start and `\b` at the end.

**Pattern details**

- `From:` - a literal string
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\K` - a match reset operator discarding all text matched so far in the overall match memory buffer
- `\b` - a word boundary  (that also means the email can't start with `-`)
- `[_a-z0-9-]+` - 1+ letters, digits, `_` or `-`
- `(?:\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of a `.` followed with 1+ letters, digits, `_` or `-`
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[a-z0-9-]+` - 1+ letters, digits or `-`
- `(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of a `.` followed with 1+ letters, digitsor `-`
- `\.` - a dot
- `[a-z]{2,4}` - two, three or four letters
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: As always, great explanation @WiktorStribizew ! Just to mention, gmail email address can contain `+` sign https://danq.me/2017/09/26/gmail-plus/

Comment: This is great and has solved the issue almost. One problem is emails in the format 'name.surname@email.com' as it is only grabbing surname@email.com. Can you help with this slight tweak?

Comment: @RHaigh You can solve that issue only if you can define the email start position context. Is it always preceded with some char? Like `mailto:` substring?

Comment: So the context I am looking for is always:

From: name.surname@email.com 
or 
From: longername@email.com

Comment: No, I mean the left-hand side context for the email part. See [this R demo](https://rextester.com/IIJ10734) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u7UDl0/3)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. The email will be always proceeded by char ```From: ``` but sometimes the subsequent email will have a . character in the name

Comment: @RHaigh Look at what you have posted: `From: Name email@email.co.uk mailto:Name@email.co.uk text text text`. You say you need to get the *last* email on a line after `From:` but you have not explained how to define the start of the last email. Well, there is a way without those details, but it is somewhat inefficient, try `rx <- "From:(?:.*?\\K[_a-z0-9-]+(?:\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\\.[a-z]{2,4})+"`, see [this R demo](https://rextester.com/AJXR72752) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u7UDl0/5).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210308/discussion-between-r-haigh-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regular expression

```
From:.*?([\w_+.]+@[\w_.]+).+?mailto:.*?([\w_+.]+@[\w_.]+)
```

Group 1 contains the email after `From:`
Group 2 contains the second email after `mailto:`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cst71E/2)

This one also works :

```
([\w_+.]+)@([\w_.]+)
```

Group 1 contains the first email in the line
Group 2 contains the second email in the line

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cst71E/1)